# Converting a character to its binary value

Tags: java

how can I get the binary value of a character
Ex: Letter C (ASCII Code= 067) To Binary value 01000011.

Comment: You got it.  A char *is* binary.

Comment: It depends.  What encoding do you want?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `Integer.toBinaryString(character...);`